# jQuery Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

This is simple login page created in asp.net but jQuery doesn't work here. I am getting this error again and again, please help me solve this.

This is my HTML markup:

```
 <html> 
   <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    User Name :<input type="text"  name="UserName" placeholder="Enter User        Name" /> <br />
    Password  :<input type="password"  name= "Password"  placeholder="Enter password"  /></br>
       <input type="button" value="Login" id="SubmitLogin" />
    </div>
    </form>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#SubmitLogin').click(function () {
        alert("I am in Submit Button click");
        Login_User();
        });
    Login_User = function () {
        postData = {UserName:'UserName1',Password:'Password1'};
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            //async:'false',
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'LoginForm.aspx/Login_validate',
            datatype: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ "dbparameters": postData }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8 ',
            success: function (outputresult) {
                alert("i am in Success " + outputresult + " .");
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, status, error) { alert("Error In System : " + status + " " + error); }
        })         
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my code-behind:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public string Login_validate(Dictionary<string, string> dbparameters) {
    string UserName, Password;
    UserName = dbparameters["UserName"];
    Password = dbparameters["Password"];
    return UserName + Password + " ";
}
```

Comment: Add [mcve] and have a look at [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I Have come to an Answer that Data sent in this request is in-coded in Double Cotes, this gives error

data sent as

```
`{"dbparameters ":{"UserName":"UserName1","Password":"_Password1"}}`
```

but this should be sent as

```
{"dbparameters ":{"UserName":UserName1,"Password":_Password1}}
```

how to do this ? this will solve Internal Server Error.

Comment: Notice "value1" and Value1.